# testing the format of winston using jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am writing test cases for winston custom format,  but here the `printf` from winston does the custom format. So how can I test the `customFormat`, using jest.

Here the `customFormat` which I am exporting is a variable, how can I test this one, in jest coverage report this line is not covered. So how can test this one

```js
//winston.js
const customFormat = printf((log) => {
  return `${log.level} -- ${log.label} -- ${log.message} `;
});


const logger = () => createLogger({
  format: combine(
    label({
      label: "test label"
    }),
    format.timestamp(),
    customFormat,
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File(options.file),
  ],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});


module.exports = {
  logger,
  customFormat,
  printf
};


// winston.test.js

describe('winton test cases', () => {
 test("check custom format is returning", () => {
   console.log(customFormt) // undeifned
   expect(customFormat).toEqual("info -- winston.js -- dummy text")
 })
})
```

Comment: How about using `winston.format.printf`? The error make sense to me since `printf` is not defined in the code you show

Comment: So how can I change the snippet

Comment: Is `printf` defined anywhere? Even without tests `winston.js` should throw an error since you are exporting an undefined variable `printf`

Comment: i am importing the printf it is defined it is a function from winston library

Comment: @Rashomon any way to test this one

Comment: I recommend not using a snippet if its no able to run. Makes the question confusing. Also, `printf` returns a `Printf` instance, not a string. So dont expect to return anything like `"info -- winston.js -- dummy text"`. Instead I would call `logger` directly. Then you would need to read your `option.file` and check if its logged correctly

Comment: but the problem is i have written the test cases for all others but when i run the coverage report the the line customFormat is not covered how can i test that one

Comment: @Rashomon i have moved out the customFormat from the logger function , check this one .And i am trying to test it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest