# calling a on the fly function inside another function

Tags: javascript

how to call the b function, since b will return the message.Please see the below snippet.

i have posted this question related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest). But i didn't get any answer so i split  the question.

how to get the string from the below snippet.

```
const a = () => {
   return b((log) => {
     return `log message will be ${log.message}`
   })
}
```

if i execute a() // it will show

```
 (log) => {
 return `log message will be ${log.message}`
}
```

confused of this format i tried a()(), but throws error, how should i call this b method

Comment: what is `b` doing?

Comment: b is a third party module function , can u check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest

Comment: Where is `log` btw?

Comment: @MaheerAli, can you check this one which is related to this i have explained it over there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest

Comment: _"i tried a()(), but throws error"_ because `a()` returns a function that expects an object with a `message` property as parameter.

Comment: @Andreas okay can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest

Answer (score 1):

By getting this function as call of `a()`,

```
(log) => {
    return `log message will be ${log.message}`
}
```

you need another call with an object for getting `log.message` in a string.

```js
const
    b = fn => fn, // assuming this
    a = () => {
        return b((log) => {
            return `log message will be ${log.message}`
        })
    };

console.log(a());
console.log(a()({ message: 'foo' }));
```

Comment: can you check this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest

Comment: any idea on jest how to test this function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491134/testing-a-function-inside-another-function-using-jest

Comment: i have no idea to this question.